# Assigning a shared_ptr to an offset of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-ptr, reference-counting

Let's say I have a `shared_ptr` to an array:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new T[10], [](T *p) { delete[] p; });
```

And a method:

```
shared_ptr<T> ptr_at_offset(int offset) {
    // I want to return a shared_ptr to (sp.get() + offset) here
    // in a way that the reference count to sp is incremented...
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is return a new `shared_ptr` that increments the reference count, but point to an offset of the original array; I want to avoid having the array deleted while a caller is using the array at some offset. If I just return `sp.get() + offset` that may happen, right? And I think initializing a new `shared_ptr` to contain `sp.get() + offset` doesn't make sense either.

New to C++, so not sure if I'm approaching this correctly.

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::array` instead of a raw array.  That let's you use `std::make_shared` and avoid the custom deleter: `auto p = std::make_shared<std::array<int, 10>>(); std::shared_ptr<int> p2{ p, &p->at(n) };`

Comment: Ah okay that's more convenient yeah

Comment: That question is a really good question. I never had the problem before but I'm thankful for the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to use the [aliasing constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

This shares the ownership with the given `shared_ptr`, but makes sure to clean up according to that one, not the pointer you give it.

```
shared_ptr<T> ptr_at_offset(int offset) {
    return {sp, sp.get() + offset};
}
```